# Finding average value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas Dataframe:

```
name        price
Hyundai     $25000
Hyundai     $35000
Peugeot     $43250
BMW         $80000
Hyundai     $23000
Peugeot     $46000
BMW         $90000
Peugeot     $30500
```

and I want to find the name that has biggest price average using pandas library.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `$` with converting values to numeric, here integers, aggregate `mean` and last get `name` by maximal value by [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
out = df['price'].str.strip('$').astype(int).groupby(df['name']).mean().idxmax()
print (out)
BMW
```

**Details**:

```
print (df['price'].str.strip('$').astype(int))
0    25000
1    35000
2    43250
3    80000
4    23000
5    46000
6    90000
7    30500
Name: price, dtype: int32

print (df['price'].str.strip('$').astype(int).groupby(df['name']).mean())
name
BMW        85000.000000
Hyundai    27666.666667
Peugeot    39916.666667
Name: price, dtype: float64
```